# Cesium vr is displayed with cardboard or oculus

Tags: virtual-reality, cesiumjs

In the cesium master version, viewer has a vrbutton, Is it using cardboard vr or oculus vr?

Answer (score 0):

*Edit:* It looks like Cesium is just doing a simple split-screen view, suitable for Google Cardboard and similar devices.

In my original answer I had thought that Cesium was using [WebVR](https://webvr.rocks/), but, after reviewing the relevant source code it looks like split-screen is all that's happening for now (as of Cesium 1.31).  I don't personally own any hardware other than Cardboard to test on, but searching for various WebVR API points does not produce any hits in Cesium 1.31 source code.  Maybe someday it will be supported.  Contributions welcome.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do not know the cesium vrbutton is using webvr or just do a split-screen view. My use of the environment: w10, nightly 55, Oculus dk2. I can use Oculus watch nightly official website example vr. But I entered cesium vrbutton, Oculus no effect, but the page was done a split-screen view. So i would like to confirm that cesium vrbutton is using cardboard vr or oculus vr?
I know there is a cesium-vr plugin in addition to cesium master. It is using Oculus vr. But I have not successfully use it. Have you used cesium vrbutton or cesium-vr plugin?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Rewrote my whole answer.  I could have sworn WebVR support was in there, but searching the source produced no results.